# How does one install a particular bootloader (e.g. from /dev/sdX#) to another EFI system partition (e.g. /dev/sdY) and NVRAM?

Tags: grub2

When running `grub-install /dev/sdY`, it seems to install the active system's bootloader (let's say we have /dev/sdX# mounted as root) into the desired EFI of sdY, and the NVRAM of the mobo.

- { `/dev/sdX#` mounted to `/`; and `grub-install /dev/sdY` } --> bootloader defined under sdX# now installed the EFI system partition(ESP) of `/dev/sdY` and NVRAM boot order (on mobo NVRAM)

How can one install the bootloader from another partition (e.g. /dev/sdZ#) as a fallback if the disk `/dev/sdY` should fail?

In particular, what exactly is going on when I run `grub-install`? I am under the impression that it compiles configuration info from various files (which files configure grub nowadays, still `grub.cfg`, or is that compiled now?), writes the output to the `/boot/grub` directory (and/or emits other files? also the `/boot/efi` directory?), may upload a stage of itself to the ESP (that in particular knows to look in `sdX` by default?), and finally hooks itself into the NVRAM boot priority list?

Possible options in `install-grub` seem to include `--bootloader-id` (presumably specify one that is not in use, then reassign the order with `efiupdatemgr`. There's also a `-d` option but how would it know what config files to use... does this mean I'd have to chroot or boot from the other partition in order to install it as a fallback bootloader? Seems like a catch-22, since it's currently unbootable... unless I can somehow make grub aware of every single valid `/boot/` config?

Thank you.

misc research notes:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing

Answer (score 0):

(use case: you can't boot off nvme drives)

Answering own question:

Finally figured it out. `grub-installer` writes to the EFI system partition(ESP) by literally just writing to `/boot/efi`. Therefore, either mount the fallback ESP there on top of the real one, or mount it somewhere else and override it with a command line parameter:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/boot/efi
mount /dev/FALLBACK /mnt/boot/efi
```

Previous to this, we should have successfully run `grub-install`, which will have written to some (let's say randomly) chosen EFI. Let's call this disk PRIMARY. Double-check that the entry in the motherboard NVRAM properly points to your first primary EFI install.

```
efibootmgr -v
ls -l /dev/disk/by-partuuid  # confirm that your first grub-install made an entry pointing to the UUID of /dev/PRIMARY
```

(these are devices, e.g. for nvme devices, you want the device-level prefix `nvme0n1` (not `nvme0`), just like `sda` or something)

Okay now we're ready:

```
grub-install --efi-directory=/mnt/boot/efi --bootloader-id=my-fallback-grub
```

Now confirm that you have two entries to two different EFI partitions:

```
efibootmgr -v
```

Adjust the order as appropriate with `efibootmgr --bootorder 3,1,2,etc`